# Plot variance and confidence interval for variance with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, data.table, variance

Consider the variables `gear` and `qsec` from the standard data set `mtcars`.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=qsec)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

**I am trying to plot the within-group variance (for each group) with error bars.**

Here is my current solution (using a 95% confidence interval for error bars):

```
require(data.table)
dtmtcars = data.table(mtcars)[,list(var.qsec = var(qsec)),by=list(gear)]
samplesize = sapply(unique(mtcars$gear), function(x) nrow(subset(mtcars, gear == x)))
high.EB =  ((samplesize-1)*dtmtcars$var.qsec)/qchisq(0.025,n-1)
low.EB = ((samplesize-1)*dtmtcars$var.qsec)/qchisq(0.975,n-1)
ggplot(dtmtcars, aes(x=gear, y=var.qsec)) + geom_point() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=low.EB, ymax=high.EB))
```

[image]

**Is there an easier solution (like an already implemented function in `ggplot2`)? If not, can you please confirm that my solution was correct?**

Comment: Strange that having only 5 observations, `gear==5` has the narrowest confidence interval.

Comment: Oh you are right indeed. I realized I made a mistake in "my solution". `samplesize` was equal for all groups. I changed it now. Thank you! Does it seem correct  to you now? Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stat_summary`. Note that the documentation is wrong when it says that `fun.data` should "take data frame as input".

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=qsec)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = var, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = function(y) {
    data.frame(y = var(y),
               ymin = ((length(y)-1)*var(y))/qchisq(0.025,length(y)-1),
               ymax = ((length(y)-1)*var(y))/qchisq(0.975,length(y)-1))
  }, geom = "errorbar") +
  ylab("var.qsec")
```

[image: resulting plot]